# rbenv - Change app ruby version but still looking in older ruby version for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, rbenv

Error message is:

```
MissingSourceFile in QuotesController#accept

no such file to load -- echo_sign

/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/martin/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/Users/martin/Desktop/[project_name]/app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:182:in `accept'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   echo_sign
```

In my controller I have:

```
require 'echo_sign'
```

My project was using ruby 1.8.7 but the gem above required 1.9.3 so I updated the ruby version of my project by first installing the newer version and then setting it locally and running `rbenv rehash`

```
rbenv local : 1.9.3-p448
rbenv global : 2.0.0-p0

ruby-v : ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

Yet the app seems to be looking in the wrong version folder for the gem, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using rvm? and which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rbenv, and it's rails 2.3.14

Comment: echo_sign is a gem? and can you see the gem installed via gem list?

Comment: yip, it's a gem. Just checked and it shows in the list.

Comment: Then you have to check if the gem is compatible with rails 2.x. Actually rails is not able to locate its index file.